# how to specify a hidden folder for the projection of a contentprovider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, mediastore

I have an app where the user must specify an image to upload to server. When the user clicks the button to choose the image and specifies an image from the Gallery, it works fine.

If the user specifies an image from a hidden folder, i get a NPE. I think its because the projection passed to the contentprovider is the mediaStore, whereas the file chosen is in a hidden folder and in a different folder to the gallery app. or should i say that the uri doesn't exist in the mediastore specified by the projection.

How can i specify a hidden folder on my sdcard instead of a folder in the mediastore when creating the projection for the contentprovider?

or if i'm missing the point here, why am i getting the NPE?

Thanks in advance

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) throws Exception {

        // try to retrieve the image from the media store first
        // this will only work for images selected from gallery
        // ^^^ Matt todo - this needs to work with images from all sources. In particular, 
        //it doesn't work with hidden Gallery images.
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        finally {
            try {
                cursor.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ignore) {
            }
        }
    }
```

.

```
08-04 20:53:58.125: D/MainActivity(10369): Single image selected: file:///storage/emulated/0/.hidden_folder/20140626_145007.jpeg
08-04 20:53:58.125: E/MainActivity(10369): Exception queueing/sending photos
08-04 20:53:58.125: E/MainActivity(10369): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
08-04 20:53:58.125: E/MainActivity(10369):  at uk.co.mobilewebexpert.infowrapsynclibrary.ApplicationObj.getPath(ApplicationObj.java:78)
08-04 20:53:58.125: E/MainActivity(10369):  at uk.co.mobilewebexpert.infowrapsynclibrary.ApplicationObj.addSinglePhotoToQueue(ApplicationObj.java:175)
08-04 20:53:58.125: E/MainActivity(10369):  at uk.co.mobilewebexpert.infowrapsyncapp.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:337)
08-04 20:53:58.125: E/MainActivity(10369):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5535)
08-04 20:53:58.125: E/MainActivity(10369):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3938)
08-04 20:53:58.125: E/MainActivity(10369):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3992)
08-04 20:53:58.125: E/MainActivity(10369):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:156)
08-04 20:53:58.125: E/MainActivity(10369):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1403)
08-04 20:53:58.125: E/MainActivity(10369):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-04 20:53:58.125: E/MainActivity(10369):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-04 20:53:58.125: E/MainActivity(10369):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
08-04 20:53:58.125: E/MainActivity(10369):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-04 20:53:58.125: E/MainActivity(10369):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
08-04 20:53:58.125: E/MainActivity(10369):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:668)
```

.

[edit1]
if i select an image from the gallery the uri selected is different. The uri below is from when i select an image fom the gallery. it work fine in this case.

```
08-04 21:37:53.285: D/MainActivity(10369): Single image selected: content://media/external/images/media/2222
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

I've just noticed that in the first log statements posted, when an image is selected from the hidden folder a path is returned anyway eg file:///

So ican simply test the uri passed in to getPath(). If the uri starts with content:// then process normally else if it starts with file:/// then simply return the uri.toString()